# Can't switch between two mobile drivers for Chrome and other react native app

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, appium, appium-android

Good afternoon,

I am trying to automate the following scenario on **Android using Kotlin**:

1. Start Appium driver and open React native app (driver1)
2. Perform some actions on React native app
3. Create driver2 with chrome options to open chrome and paste deep link there
4. Deeplink leads to the app automatically (but I suppose the current session uses driver2, not driver1 here)
5. I need to continue using the app further with driver1 however it is not working and not finding the element which is on the next screen where my deep link leaded me

**I am using Appium v1,21,0**

**Language - Kotlin**

**App - React-native**

I tried the following solutions:

- **getContext** - does not work as this is not a hybrid app but two different mobile apps
- **startActivity** - it actually launching the app from scratch, not continuing (i need to be on a particular screen after deep-link navigation, can't navigate anywhere else flow won't work)
- **startActivityCommand** - this one did not work for me at all (it ignores the command but maybe anyone can give an example of its usage as I might use it wrong)
- **driver.switchTo().window("0")** - did not work
- **assign to driver2(web) new capabilities** - does not work as it is already defined so we cant change it
- **sessionId** - I am not sure how it works exactly yet, but I tried to find a way to assign a driver to the particular session-id and was not successful (looks like AppiumDriver methods do not support it)

Would appreciate any ideas, links, or sources that can help archive the above
Good Day!

Answer (score 0):

Solution that helped:

```
    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.EditText[@resource-id=\"com.android.chrome:id/search_box_text\"]")
    @iOSXCUITFindBy(id = "")
    lateinit var chromeURL: MobileElement        


var deeplink = <your deeplink>
driver.activateApp("com.android.chrome")
chromeURL.sendKeys(deepLink) 
var clickOnDeepLink = driver.findElements(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().text(\"$deepLink\")"))
        clickOnDeepLink[0].click() //here we could not use Keys.ENTER so we just click on the element first in the list - default android google chrome behaviour
```

So there is no need for several drivers - same driver instance is fine